How to consolidate duplicate values of different Lengths in SQL Server?
Here is my query:
SELECT 
    *, 
    LEN(Test) LENofTEST, 
    DATALENGTH(Test) DataLENofTEST, 
    CAST(Test AS VARBINARY(30)) ExtraColumn
FROM
    (SELECT 
         TRIM(SOS1 + ',' + REPLACE(PANO20, ' ', '')) AS 'Test', 
         COUNT(SOS1 + ',' + REPLACE(PANO20, ' ', '')) AS 'COUNTR'
     FROM 
         MyServerName.dbo.MyTableName
     WHERE 
         PANO20 LIKE '%701001207%'
     GROUP BY 
         TRIM(SOS1 + ',' + REPLACE(PANO20, ' ', ''))) A

These are my results :
Test            COUNTR   LENofTEST   DataLENofTEST   ExtraColumn
-----------------------------------------------------------------
100,701001207   1        13             13   0x3130302C373031303031323037
100,701001207   1        14             14   0x3130302C373031303031323037A0
123,701001207   1        13             13   0x3132332C373031303031323037

My issue is with the first two rows. They should be identical in length and therefore COUNTR should be 2.
But for some reason, SQL is calling them different values of different lengths.
How do I go about adjusting my query so that those are counted as the same 'Test'? Obviously I want to do it systemically and repeatably.
Thank you in advance!

You need to provide some sample data.

Can you add CAST(Test AS VARBINARY(30)) so we see the extra character that isn't apparent in your post

I'm guessing they contain some "weird" spaces, have to remove them first

@MartinSmith I added the extra column

That is a "non-breaking space". What version of SQL Server are you on? Does it support [ characters FROM ] argument to TRIM? i.e. TRIM(CHAR(0xA0) + ' ' FROM ...)

@MartinSmith I am on SQL Server Management Studio 18. I do believe so . I see it when I type out the Function

I think it is only the LEADING/TRAILING/ BOTH keywords that are version specific anyway so you should be good to add an explicit list in any version supporting TRIM

I think it is simply your group by is not the same as your select ie REPLACE(DUMP(PANO20)) vrs REPLACE(PANO20)

@KevinBosch That was just an error when I pasted.  I have fixed it

The trailing A0 is a "non breaking space"
Instead of doing
TRIM(Foo)

(Which only trims off regular spaces by default)
You can do
TRIM(NCHAR(0x0020) /*SP*/ + NCHAR(0x00A0) /*NBSP*/ + NCHAR(0x200B) /*ZWSP*/ FROM Foo)

To trim off a greater variety of spaces.
See the Whitespace Character Wikipedia article for other possibilities you might want to add.

I'm sorry, I guess I am still a little bit confused.  So, how do I modify my code using this so that the 'COUNTR' for the top 2 rows shows 2 instead of 1?

Figured it out, thank you!
